# React native axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I am fetching data by axios for react native but keep showing error message like this. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async() =>{
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => {person.name})}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I install axios, error message appeared:

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "axios" under a package
npm ERR! also called "axios". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-06-15T19_16_16_279Z-debug.log
```

Comment: How do you import axios?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant information there.

Comment: done. Thanks in advance. I am totally confused.

Comment: No problem. Did you install axios?

Comment: error message shown

Comment: Again.. Please add relevant information to your question.

Comment: in what directory did you try to install axios? and what command did you type?

Comment: the same directory with App.js which contains the above code

Comment: npm install axios

Comment: Axios has some compatibility issues with React Native. You can use the native 'fetch' library in place of Axios.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
fetchData = async() =>{
```

with

```
fetchData = () =>{
```

You are already handling the axios Promise, so your async function doesn't even return a Promise, but expects to because you've declared it as async. You function must not be async, as it doesn't do async stuff.